# Unexpected scrollbar in Reporting Services

Tags: html, iframe, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I try to display `reporting service` report in iframe, and i have a interesting issue. Sometimes, but not always, there is some extra horizontal scrollbar. Solution have to work only in `IE 9, 10, 11`. I could not find any rule, why it happens. 
**Problem dissapears**, when i hide header of report using rc:Toolbar=false. It occurs only in iframe.

Reporting Services 2008 R2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution. 
Issue occurs because parent document has html doctype and it is rendered by current IE engine. Default Reporting Services template has line like:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

I found information, that IE cannot render document inside iframe using different engine.

I deleted this line and changed doctype to "html". Problem disappeared

Comment: Hi, just wondering how you managed to implement this solution. I can find javascript and CSS files associated with the report but can't find the HTML to make the necessary changes. Was yours a static page or generated dynamically somehow?

Comment: @milks Reporting services web service has default html template file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services)