# Corrupted UI when trying to display reporting service report in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, reporting-services

I need to display report services reports using an iframe which is opened from a web application that supports IE9, IE10, IE11 (the application cannot run with computability view).

When using the iframe, the UI of the displayed report is corrupted, as you can see in the attached screenshot. Seems that it happens when using iframes in general, not only from our application.

We cannot change the reporting services html on the customers machine, so this suggested solution can't assist us: [Unexpected scrollbar in Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742793/unexpected-scrollbar-in-reporting-services)[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you grow your iframes' content so there are no scrolls?

Comment: In what way is the UI corrupted? I would first check elements inside the iframe using IE, FF, or Chrome Dev Tools (F12). Inspect the CSS, look for JavaScript errors in the console. Is this an intranet site? Internet? Since RS elements are being displayed inside an iframe, I would check for double-hop issues with NTLM or Kerberos depending on what you're using. I've had problems with NTLM double-hop issues when viewing RS pages over VPN on a SharePoint site. Not sure if my comments will help but it's all I can offer with the information provided. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Following up@ @jtbon2's answer - if this iframe is running on your company's intranet and you are inside of the same network with your development machine, your Internet Explorer might have the default option for compatibility mode enabled for local sites.

It will essentially downgrade your browser to a lower version of IE to enforce a a standard IE user base.